# Why does running SparkSQL on DStreams give ClassCastException for org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDDPartition?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, apache-spark-sql

Getting ClassCastException when running SparkSQL on each RDD in DStream.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDDPartition cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD.compute(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD.compute(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that leads to the issue? What version of Spark do you use?

Comment: I was using Spark 1.0.2 version but when I changed the version to 1.1.0 the error gone away but facing different ClassCast error.Following is the error :    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4 cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency

Comment: Did you find a solution to the new error you were getting?

Comment: @bfaskiplar yes  i found the solution the error was due to mismatch version of spark core and spark streaming jars